# How to extract datetime string SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I want a datetime string till minute from Datetime in sql server. Means I want to extract string after minute from Datetime from sql server.

Like:  `2011-11-02 13:35:14.613`

and I want this from above datetime string -

```
2011-11-02 13:35
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a bit tricky, because the default formats which `CONVERT()` offers do not match your expected output.  However, format style `120` has the following format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

This is *almost* what you want, minus the `:ss` at the end.  To get rid of that, you can just `SUBSTRING()` it off after calling `CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, yourDateColumn, 120), 1, 16)
```

Comment: Or simply `SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(16), @date, 120)` No need for substrings, no need for varchars. simply convert to the size of the char needed and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, will give you the date in format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm` as a string.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(16),'2011-11-02 13:35:14.613',120)
```

You can use your column name instead of the static date.

Comment: 103 returns the string format `dd/MM/yyyy` Not only will it not produce the correct format, it will also truncate the time part completely.

Comment: Np. now all your answer needs to be great is change `nvarchar` to `char`. this is a fixed length string that will never contain any unicode-only chars so it's there really is no need to use `nvarchar` here.